# OpenCV Assertion Error in Stitching

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm doing stitching on two images, and has this error while debugging(compile successfully but when run it breaks):

Assertion failed ==CV_8Uc3> in unknown function.

And here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    Mat im1=imread("panorama_image1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat im2=imread("panorama_image2.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    Mat result;
    vector<Mat> imgs;
    imgs.push_back(im1);
    imgs.push_back(im2);
    cv::Stitcher stitcher=cv::Stitcher::createDefault(false);
    stitcher.stitch(imgs,result);

    namedWindow("Mosaic", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Mosaic",result);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

I've not been able to find an error in this code. And the linker libraries are correct(use D version such as `opencv_core244d.lib`, `opencv_stitching244d.lib` etc

Comment: May be the function `stitcher.stitch(imgs,result);` expects input images of type **8 bit, 3 channels**. Try loading the images as colored.

Comment: I'm not sure, but input to stitch should be grayscale right? Usually it's easier to stitch grayscale images. And the code works perfectly on Ubuntu. I have problem on Windows and Visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I think [sgarizvi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1231073/sgarizvi) is right, loading in color solved a similar problem for me:

```
Mat im1=imread("panorama_image1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
Mat im2=imread("panorama_image2.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```